# Remote Desktop Connetion Software Detection

Tags: virtual-machines, remote-desktop, remote

I´m using windows server 2012. And I have hyper V with x machines. That people connect to work.
 I have software in that machine, is possible for that software to know if that is a remote connection , is possible for them to query info , and find out about it? Or that the machine I´m using is a virtual machine?

I´m askying this because I don´t want the software company to know that it is being used in remote connection and in a virtual machine. Do I explain myself.

If they can query for that info. What can I do to prevent that?

Any info that anyone can provide me . I will be thankfull.

Comment: So, you want to violate the terms of your licensing agreement? I am sorry, but SF is the **absolutely wrong place** to ask this kind of questions. Please read our [FAQ]. And hire a good lawyer in case you get caught.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to skirt licensing restrictions or supported configuration concerns I suggest you abandon the idea. It is fairly trivial for application software to "detect" it is being executed in a VM and/or over Remote Desktop.

Preventing either would be difficult w/o modifying the application's code. Obscuring the hypervisor's virtual hardware might get you something, but then you're probably talking about modifying the hypervisor (likely in violation of license terms).